# how would you write this sentence in predicate logic?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

All Mary’s relatives live in Boston, only her cousin John lives in New-York.

I'm confused about how should I translate the second part, whithout getting a contradiction.

Comment: I believe "only" has the same meaning as "but" in this case, which is made into "and" for predicate logic.

Answer (score 1):

For all x, if [ (x is a relative of Mary) and (x is not Mary's cousin John)] then x lives in Boston. AND Mary's cousin John lives in New York.

The "AND" here goes between the two, so overall it's a conjunction of two different predicate statements.

To make it look better one could invent predicates like $Rxy$ for x is a relative of y, and so on.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I think you're right, and also that is shorter than my version...

Comment: As Jean-Claude has explained, my version can be shortened a bit.

Comment: Thank you all, that's really what I've been looking for!